# Create a custom extension with a Batch-File

Tags: file, batch-file

I'm working on a Batch Project and i wanted to know if it possible to make custom file extension like the other softwares or games that make, and most of them make it for saving progress and i know how to save something with Batch file to a file here is the code :

```
echo This is a test >"Directory\Filename.FileExtension"
```

and if wanted multiple lines you can use :

```
echo Line1 >"Directory\Filename.FileExtension"
echo Line2 >>"Directory\Filename.FileExtension"
echo Line3 >>"Directory\Filename.FileExtension"
echo Line4 >>"Directory\Filename.FileExtension"
```

And if it possible i will be appreciated if someone told me, And Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It's possible, and commonly done. You could have tried it yourself in less time than it took to create your question!

Comment: What was stopping you from trying anything you wanted for the file extension? It's not magic.

Comment: Well, you just did it in your question, why not do it in a batch and see?

Comment: The file extension is just a part of the whole file name and it does not make any file special. A file is just a stream of data, that's it, so you can name it as you like. Anyway, don't do `echo text > file.ext`, write `> file.ext echo text` instead, because otherwise the _space_ before `>` becomes part of the output and so in turn part of the file contents...